# How to pass latitude and longitude from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am building an app where I am using Firebase cloud messaging and Location Fused Prodiver. I want to send upstream message with latitude and longitude. And button for that is on my Dashboard Fragment, and function where I am getting lat and long is on MainActivity. How to pass that latitude and longitude to that button for upstream on my Dashboard fragment?

This is my MainActivity:

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    protected void createLocationRequest(){
        mLocationRequest=new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(!isGooglePlayServiceAvailable()){
            finish();
        }

        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d("OnResume", "Location update resumed .....................");
        }

        readTokenFromSharedPreferences();

        super.onResume();
    }

    public void readTokenFromSharedPreferences() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Token_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final  String strPref = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null);

        if(strPref == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    private boolean isGooglePlayServiceAvailable(){
        int status= GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status){
            return true;
        }else{
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        startLocationUpdates();


    }
    protected void startLocationUpdates(){
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation=location;

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d("Lokacije", "Location update stopped .......................");
    }
    private void LatitudeLongitude(){
        if(mCurrentLocation!=null){
            String latitude=String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            String longitude=String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());



        }
    }


}
```

This function LatitudeLongitude() is for getting latitude and longitude. How to pass this function(or just this strings latitude and longitude) to my Dashboard fragment where is a button for upstream message?
This is my upstream message button on Dashboard frgament:

```
  String latitude, longitude;
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    latitude=bundle.getString("KEY_LAT");
    longitude=getArguments().getString("KEY_LNG");
    Log.d("LONGITUDE", "Longitude je: " + latitude);
    Gson data_json = new Gson();
    String json=data_json.toJson(data);
    FirebaseMessaging fm=FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
    fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
            .setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .addData("action","message")
            .addData("data","{\"message\":\"Upstream Message\"}")
            .addData("object", json)
            .addData("sss", latitude)
            .addData("latitude", latitude)
            .build());
```

Could anyone help me?

EDIT:This is my logcat when I use bundle:

```
08-08 10:01:41.195 27695-27695/com.telnet.asp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                at com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.fragments.DashboardFragment.getObjectEvent(DashboardFragment.java:125)
                                                                at com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.adapters.DashboardGridAdapter.getDataObject(DashboardGridAdapter.java:145)
                                                                at com.telnet.asp.presentation.view.adapters.DashboardGridAdapter$3.onClick(DashboardGridAdapter.java:128)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your fragment, add two variables,

`double lat,lng;`

the make there setters, getters:

```
public void setLat(double lat){

    this.lat = lat;

}

public void setLng(double lng){

    this.lng = lng;
}
```

andin your fragment manager in the activity, pass the variables:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
fragment.setLat(lat);
fragment.setLng(lng);
FragmentTransaction tr = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tr.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are basically talking about communication between **Activity** and **Fragment**.

You can do so easily by passing the strings in **Bundle**.

```
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY_LAT", latitude);
bundle.putString("KEY_LNG", longitude);
fragment.setArguments(fragment);
```

So, the idea if pretty simple. You just put the latitude and longitude strings into the bundle and **pass the bundle to the fragment before replacing or adding it** using the fragment manager.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

In the fragment's `onViewCreated()` method do this,

```
String latitude, longitude;
latitude = getArguments().getString("KEY_LAT");
longitude = getArguments().getString("KEY_LNG");
```

This is how you can fetch the data previously send from the Activity inside the Fragment.

Comment: And what should I do in part with upstream message?

Comment: When I write this yours code, what should I do then in Dashboard fragment?

Comment: Updated the answer, please check.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer. Or let me know if you have nay more problems.

Comment: You need to show your new code for me to help you further. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my question and I have posted my logcat when I used your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them from the Activity to the Fragment like @Khalid said, but you can also retrieve them on the Fragment.
**Basically the Fragment asks the Activity** for the Latitude and Longitude.
Have the following variables defined on your Activity:

```
String latitude = "latitude you want";
String longitude = "longitude you want";

public Pair<String,String> getLatitudeAndLongitude(){
    return new Pair<>(latitude,longitude);
}
```

and then, in your fragment call it the method for it

```
...
Pair latitudeAndLongitude = ((YourActivity) getActivity()).getLatitudeAndLongitude();
p.first; // latitude
p.second; // longitude
...
```